# rss feed thumbnail image

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I am trying to show the images in rss feed and would appreciate help please.

**Here is my code**

```
<?php
function fetch_news(){
    $data = file_get_contents('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
    $data = simplexml_load_string($data);

    foreach ($data->channel->item as $item) {
    $media = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

          print_r($media->thumbnail[0]->attributes());

        }

}

?>
```

and i am getting the folloing error

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function `attributes()` on a non-object in `C:\wamp\www\ourProject\inc\news_reader.php`

Comment: the interpreter is not lying, `$media->thumbnail[0]` is non-object.

Comment: then what should i write?

Comment: find out why  `$media->thumbnail[0]` a non object.